# Selecting first number not in an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, numbers

I have the following problem but I will simplify it here:

```
$starting = 0;
$arrayOfNumbersToSkip = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6];
$ending = 7;
```

Part 1: Give me the first number available? "Answer is 2"

Part 2: Give me the next number available? "Answer is 7"

This is a simplified version of a math problem im facing, im designing a dynamic approval system that modifies the entire program based on changeable rules.

Comment: Will the array always be sorted. Will it always have consecutive numbers?

Comment: Sorted, at least that is the good part

Comment: It looks like you are abusing the volunteers here as a free coding service.  Please always "try something" and research before posting a question.  Your question is what is referred to here as a "requirements dump" <-- not good.

Comment: Your question is Too Broad because you need to 1. Create an array from a starting point and length declaration (how to use `range()`) and 2. How to filter an array using a blacklist array (how to use `array_diff()`) and 3. How to extract the first value from an array (how to use `array_shift()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) with a [`range`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) from `$starting+1` to `$ending`:

```
$availableNumbers = array_diff(range($starting+1, $ending), $arrayOfNumbersToSkip);
if (!count($availableNumbers)) {
    echo "no numbers available\n";
}
else {
    echo "first number available = " . array_shift($availableNumbers);
}
print_r($availableNumbers);
```

Output:

```
first number available = 2
Array
(
    [0] => 7
)
```

The output shows that there are still available numbers (you can keep using [`array_shift`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) to get them) after taking `2` from the array.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/li5bU)

Comment: @KhalilGhanem it only works as long as `$availableNumbers` is sorted. Otherwise you need a `sort($availableNumbers);` beforehand.